# Por que userRepository es undefined?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express, clean-architecture

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejemplo de api rest en node y express aplicando clean architecture, pero veo un error del cual no estoy entendiendo el porqué:

En mi app.ts instancio MongooseUserRepository: `const userRepository = new MongooseUserRepository();` el cual lo inyecto a UserController también al instanciarlo: `const userController = new UserController(userRepository)`. Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es cuando se usa el endpoint.

El error que obtengo es:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userRepository')
    at D:\Proyectos\TYPESCRIPT\example\src\adapters\express\controllers\UserController.ts:14:62
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\Proyectos\TYPESCRIPT\example\src\adapters\express\controllers\UserController.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Lo veo muy raro ya que devuelve undefined cuando al instanciarlo en el app.ts automáticamente se ejecuta el constructor, y luego de instanciar recién hago el llamado a registerUser.

en mi app.ts:

```
import express from 'express';
import { DB_NAME, MONGO_URL, PORT } from './constants';
import { connectToMongoDB } from './infraestructure/persistence/mongoose/database';
import UserController from './adapters/express/controllers/UserController';
import { MongooseUserRepository } from './infraestructure/persistence/repositories/UserRepository';

const app = express();
const myPort = process.env.PORT || PORT;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Conectar a la base de datos MongoDB
connectToMongoDB(MONGO_URL, DB_NAME)

// Rutas
const userRepository = new MongooseUserRepository();
const userController = new UserController(userRepository);
app.post('/user', userController.registerUser)

app.listen(myPort, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor iniciado en http://localhost:${myPort}`);
});
```

en mi UserRepository.ts:

```
import UserModel from '../mongoose/UserModel';
import { User } from '../../../domain/entities/User';
import { IUserRepository } from '../../../adapters/interfaces/IUserRepository';

export class MongooseUserRepository implements IUserRepository {
    async createUser(user: User): Promise<void> {
        const userModel = new UserModel({
            name: user.name,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            motherLastname: user.motherLastname,
            phone: user.phone,
            email: user.email,
            authentication: {
                username: user.authentication.username,
                password: user.authentication.password,
            }
            
        });

        await userModel.save();
    }

}
```

y en mi UserController.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { User } from '../../../domain/entities/User';
import { Authentication } from '../../../domain/entities/Authentication';
import { IUserRepository } from '../../interfaces/IUserRepository';

class UserController {
    userRepository: IUserRepository

    constructor(userRepository: IUserRepository) {
        console.log('Antes de Inicializar: > ', userRepository) // <--- parametro de entrada definido
        this.userRepository = userRepository
        console.log('despues de inicializar: >', this.userRepository) // <--- userRepository definido
    }

    async registerUser(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        console.log('Al querer mostrar userRepository: >', this.userRepository) // <--- userRepository indefinido ???
        
        const {
            name,
            lastname,
            motherLastname,
            phone,
            email,
            username,
            password
        } = req.body;

        try {
            const newUser = new User(
                name,
                lastname,
                motherLastname,
                phone,
                email,
                new Authentication(username, password)
            );

            await this.userRepository.createUser(newUser)

            res.status(201).json({ mensaje: 'Usuario registrado con éxito.' });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ mensaje: 'Error al registrar el usuario.' });
        }
    }
}

export default UserController;
```

y eso es lo que no entiendo porqué en el constructor, tanto el parámetro de entrada como la variable *this.userRepository* tienen sus valores asignados. Pero cuando ejecuto el *console.log()* en el *registerUser* devuelve **indefinido** y no tengo idea del porqué.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el metodo `registerUser` no tiene contexto del `this` de tu clase. Tienes dos posibles soluciones:

```
//Asignar this mediante el bind
app.post('/user', userController.registerUser.bind(userController))

//usar una función anonima
app.post('/user', (req, res)=>userController.registerUser(req, res))
```